# What happend if flat and sharp in one line before any of them neutralized?

Tags: sheet-music

its back normal or following the new rule?
for example `E-flat hits sharp rule became E` and `E-flat hits flat rule became D`
or back to E-Flat?

Comment: It says to play an E natural and then an E flat. that's what you play.

Comment: but in front of e flat there is sharp? so its not affected? i must follow new rule?

Comment: i think if there is sharp you must keep playing sharp before second sign

Comment: Are you talking about inside the red box? There is no sharp there. It goes to E natural and then back to E flat.

Comment: oh sorry my fault, yes that is natural

Comment: no problem. But if you can find an example of what your original question was it would be good to have on the site.

Comment: i will update the question soon :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you have mistaken the natural sign for the sharp sign.
The natural sign destroys sharps and flats. This is why a new flat is added after the natural sign, to make it flat again.
There are no sharps here. This is a sharp: #
The key signature shows you all the flats in this piece : B, E, A
If you want an E natural you have to write the natural sign but it only will affect all the E's in that measure. In the next measure if you want an E natural again you will have to write the natural sign again.
I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In the red box there is an E nat then an Eb. What it says is what gets played, regardless of key Sig. The sign directly before a note is the definitive. Note that after the Eb is re-established (*re*, since as stated in the key signature), the next E in the same bar also is played Eb.

Here there are two more, both Eb.